# Cómo puedo establecer una fila especifica como header en sheetjs

Tags: javascript, sheetjs

Tengo una hoja de Excel y quiero convertirla a un arreglo de objetos con Sheetjs pero con una particularidad. Tomar la 2da linea como header de los datos. Por ejemplo, tengo esta estructura:

```
/***** Excel file *****
   (A)     (B)     (C)
(1)Titulo
(2)num1   num2     val
(3) 1       1        2
(4) 2       2        4
(5) 3       3        6
(6) 4       4        8
***********************/
```

Donde si especifico como segunda linea el header y no la primera como es por defecto, el arreglo que genero sería tal así:

```
[{num1: 1, num2: 1, val: 2}, {num1: 2, num2: 2, val: 4},...]
```

Pero según el código que tengo y tomando la primera linea como header, me da esto:

```
[{Titulo: 'num1', __EMPTY: 'num2', __EMPTY: 'val'}, {Titulo: 1, __EMPTY: 1, __EMPTY: 2},...]
```

¿Hay alguna manera? Lo que pasa es que se importarán archivos con esa estructura establecida y no se pueden estar modificando. Esto es lo que tengo, ¿Dónde agregaría o cambiaría para lograrlo?

```
const fileName = './example.xlsx';
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(fileName);
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
```

Gracias por su atención y ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Para obtener los datos de un excel puede usar este código:

```
const workbook = await XLSX.readFile(file.path);

const workbookSheets = workbook.SheetNames;

const sheet = workbookSheets[0];

const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet];

const worksheetData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 });

const headers = worksheetData[1];

const dataExcel = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: headers }).slice(2);
```

El slice es apartir de la fila donde se encuentra la información. En su caso particular podrá ver en consola:

```
const result = [{num1: 1, num2: 1, val: 2}, {num1: 2, num2: 2, val: 4},...]
```

2. Para crear un excel a partir de un arreglo:

Debe especificarle cuáles son los headers que desea utilizar y el origen de donde se pondrán los mismos.

El tipo de dato de los headers es un array compuesto de varios strings (los títulos):

```
const headers = ["Nombre","Apellido", "Telefono"];
```

Acá hay un ejemplo del código que suelo usar para crear los documentos de excel en mis proyectos:

- Crea el excel:

```
const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
```

- Agrega la información del documento:

```
const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(dataRows);
```

- Le agrega los títulos y el origen desde donde empezarán:

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [headers], { origin: "A1" });
```

- Nombra la hoja que desea utilizar:

```
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Clientes");
```

- Almacena el documento en la storage:

```
const newFileName = `${uuidv4()}.xlsx`;

XLSX.writeFileXLSX(workbook, `./storage/uploads/${newFileName}`);
```

Por último no olvide instalar las librerías: `npm i xlsx uuid`

Comment: Es genial esta información! Gracias por eso pero lo que busco es al revés. Quiero convertir un archivo excel existente a un JSON. Por defecto SheetJS toma la primera fila como los headers del JSON pero yo deseo que los tome de la segunda linea del excel. ¿Hay alguna manera?

Comment: Listo. Edité el código y podrás ver como realizar los procesos de ambas formas